# SQLite 3 prevent rows where all values are duplicates

Tags: c++, sqlite, insert, duplicates

I'm wondering how I can go about creating a table that won't allow rows to be inserted that are COMPLETE duplicates.  By complete I mean every value has to be the same.

I'm okay with inserting rows that are identical other than 1 column's value, but not if they are all the same.

I know you can use INSERT OR IGNORE to avoid inserting duplicate rows, but the problem is that my table uses an auto incremented integer for its primary key, and INSERT OR IGNORE will still allow duplicate rows to be inserted as it sees the auto incremented id as different

Ex.

Running

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table VALUES ("A", "B" "C");
```

twice will give me the following table:

```
id | Column A | Column B | Column C
1.    "A"         "B"        "C"
2.    "A"         "B"        "C"
```

Is there any way around this other than manually searching rows (ignoring id) for duplicates?

Comment: put in a unique key that covers all of the relevant fields in the table. e.g. `unique key 'foo' (a,b,c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSERT OR IGNORE will check *any* constraint, so just add one on the fields you want to check:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    ColumnA INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ColumnB WHATEVER,
    ColumnC,
    UNIQUE (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
);
```

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I still want the ability to add columns that have SOME columns the same. 
So (A, B, C) and (A, D, C) should still work, as should (A, B, C) (X, Y, C) etc..

If I declare A B and C as unique, won't it ignore any inserts where A OR B OR C are the same?

Comment: This constraint does what you want.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I guess my understanding of UNIQUE was incorrect  If I had instead done: Unique(ColumnA), Unique(ColumnB), Unique(ColumnC). Would that have checked to make sure every column was unique individually?